# Implementing a 100% portable php application

Tags: php, deployment, include, hierarchy

I am seeking a way of allowing my PHP applications to be perfectly portable. My problem is, although I am utilizing relative path to include PHP classes, I always face issues when I try to deploy me application in a new environment.

For example, I have implemented an application under Ubuntu and it just run perfectly. However, when I moved it to a shared hosting running Centos, I had to modify all the include statements.

So, I am asking about the best way to include classes, considering having multiple folders which contain various classes that are dependent on another multiple classes in different levels of the folder hierarchy.

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Yes, because for example it would be '/var/www/myapp' in one machine but '/var/username/www/myapp' in another machine. And maybe '/var/username/www/myapp' in some instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just keep one "main" folder.

In your index.php (for ex.) configure the "main" folder location and either use that as the 'base' for includes (I suppose you hard-code the include/require path?)

Else use the 'base' within the autoload functionality.

Now you are able to move the 'main' folder around and all you need to do is update just one line of code in your index.php

It is still a manual update. True that. You can also ofc. use something like glob() and search for you "mainlib.php" file (for ex.) and 'cache' that folders location to use it in the next calls?

---

This for example is how I do it:

```
<?php
/**
 * cfg.php
 *
 * Main config file
 *
 * @package Public
 */

// Compatibility
$version = '5.2.3';//restricted by htmlentities()' 4th parameter
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $version, '<')) {
    die('Required PHP version is ' . $version . ', current is ' . PHP_VERSION);
}

// Environment
define('DEVELOPMENT', in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1')));
define('PRIVATE_DIR', DEVELOPMENT ? 'private' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'private_html'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tickets');
define('APPLICATION_LINK','application_red'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('LIBRARY_LINK','library'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("MEM_START",memory_get_usage(true));

// Behavior
if(DEVELOPMENT) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);//report all errors
}
else {
    ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    error_reporting(0);
}

// Timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

// Constants
define('ROOT',  dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('APP',   ROOT . '..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.PRIVATE_DIR.''.APPLICATION_LINK);
define('LIB',   ROOT . '..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.PRIVATE_DIR.''.LIBRARY_LINK);
define('CACHE', APP.'cache'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

index.php/utest.php:

```
<?php
include("cfg.php");

// Start library
require_once LIB.'Library.php';
$library = new Library();
//etc.......
```

Comment: But index.php will not be my start point of all files. I will be having files like this: index.php add.php download.php control.php and so on. I don't want to put the main folder location in all of them.

Comment: use something like config.php within that same root folder? and include that file in your other files?

Comment: I was looking for a better solution. Anyway, thank you for your answer. As it is the only reasonable answer here, I will accept it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my real life example of how I do it with my framework. It runs on any server that I am running on. As well on windows as on linux. Also, I always wait atleast a day before accepting answers. But still thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make reference to a hardwired folder at all. In my current project I do this:

```
public static function getProjectRoot()
{
    return realpath(
        dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'
    );
}
```

The class in which this features is two folder levels inside the project - hence the two .. operators to traverse up the directory structure. Since that location will never change in relation to the project root, this doesn't need changing, and I don't ever need to hardwire any paths.

Edit: in relation to include/require statements, use an autoloader, and (apart from a couple of bootstrap files) you don't generally need to use includes/requires at all.

Comment: Incidentally you can use `__DIR__` too, but only from PHP5.3.

Comment: I had some trouble with __DIR__ when Rewrites were on in Apache. Especially with `/project/path/index.php` using `/project/path/api/index.php` via URI eg. `localhost:5000/api/v1/something` which uses includes in the `.../api/index.php`. I think the best solution is indeed to use a hard-coded rootpath variable, which you simply change in different environments/servers, and then use that as the root for all includes.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen: that's odd, `__DIR__` shouldn't be affected by `mod_rewrite`. It is used to traverse the directory structure, not the URL structure.